# How to identify from which shared library in folder this particular undefined symbol belongs?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Currently I am building a legacy C++ project with nbind (https://github.com/charto/nbind) and while executing command npm run -- node-gyp configure build I am getting error undefined symbol: _ZN3dsr8Employee8getAll, and I know that this symbol will be in present in some shared library in particular folder so my question is given a symbol how to find corresponding shared library in folder. I am currently using linux system and when i say shared library basically it's .so files.

Comment: run `nm lib.so | grep "_ZN3dsr8Employee8getAll"` on all libs in that folder perhaps?

Comment: Actually question is there are multiple so files in same folder so i have to identify particular lib.so only so that i can include that in binding.gyp (makefile) file

Comment: right, and presumably only one of these .so files contains the symbol you are looking for, so only that one file will output something when you run my suggested command on it.

Comment: Addendum: On second thought you probably want to use `nm -D` in that case.

Comment: Thanks nm -D *|grep "_ZN3dsr8Employee8getAll" worked for me

Comment: @Frank This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the command that finally worked for me is:

nm --print-file-name *|grep _ZN3dsr8Employee8getAll